# How can i get country name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, country

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where  i tried lots for get user country means user open my site in which `country` that i want to get.

I tried

```
> Geocoder where too much load and not get proper output
> jQuery /Javascript code but always ask to user for share location which one is not good way
> geoip where get only ip country which always return server ip location not user browser location
```

Any other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have used [gem 'maxmind_geoip2', github: 'envato/geoip2'](https://github.com/da4nik/geoip2) in our app.
You need a mmdb file for it that you can get from the gem page. 

Configure that gem as: 

          MaxmindGeoIP2.file 'local_db_file.mmdb' 
           MaxmindGeoIP2.locale 'en' # default: 'ru'

After that , you can get the IP of the user by using request.remote_ip in any request.

Just parse that IP using  MaxmindGeoIP2.locate() . It will return you with a hash of the location details such as city, country, timezone etc..